# Rotation field is missing in rule-based renderer in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based

I am trying to do rotation of point symbols in QGIS. I am working with rule-based renderer. In other types of classification there is a button advanced (for example in categorized renderer), where I can choose rotation field.
But in rule-based renderer this button is missing.

Do you know how to make this rotation of point symbols otherwise?

Example in categorized renderer
[image]

In rule-based renderer advanced(and rotation field) is missing
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it manually. Not so ellegant, but works.

In *.qml style, I can edit part with

```
< prop k="angle" v="0"/ >
```

and instead of it write

`< prop k="angle_expression" v="ROT"/ >` , 
where `ROT` is my field with rotation.

Edit: In version 2.10 there is a new field in rule-based renderer- "change angle".
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the **Advanced** options if you click on a rule you made and select *Refine current rules* > *Add categories to rule* **or** *Add ranges to rule* > *Advanced* > *Rotation field*:

[image: Advanced options]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But still I have a problem, because I am rotating font markers and it doesn't work in rule-based renderer. When I try your solution with predefined Qgis markers- it works, but it doesn't work with mine own markers. I think that this is maybe QGIS bug or something is wrong with my fonts... :-/

Comment: @Kristy - I am not sure as I never really worked with the _rotation_ options, I just remembered that there was an option for it. Hopefully others can advise =)

Comment: @Kristy please try the latest version of QGIS and report a bug if this is still a problem. Thanks!

Comment: @underdark I just tried version 2.10. and they added a lot of new stuff including field "change angle" in rule-based renderer! great!